# How to get the full path of a file by using UIDocumentPickerViewController?

Tags: swift, xcode

```
@IBAction func search(_ sender: Any) {
    let pickerView = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["mp3"], in: .open)

    pickerView.delegate = self
    self.present(pickerView, animated: true)

    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        let start = urls[0]
         NSLog("\(start)")

     }
}
```

For example,

When I click the button called "search", I'd like to select a file and when I select the file, I'd like to get the full path. I'm not sure if UIDocumentPickerViewController is used for this.

Answer (score 0):

Delegate methods must be always located on the top level of the class

```
@IBAction func search(_ sender: Any) {
    let pickerView = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["mp3"], in: .open)
    pickerView.delegate = self
    self.present(pickerView, animated: true)
}

func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
    let start = urls[0]
    print(start)
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I don't see the path though. I just put my file onto application folder on my Mac and started simulator and clicked the button and dragged the file onto "On My iPhone" I think I did something wrong somewhere..